# Check for a list of strings (words) in a text (phrase)

Tags: r

Is there an elegant way, other than looping, to test if a word which belong to a list is found in a phrase?
I'm thinking something like list comprehension of one of the `apply` functions.
Ex:

```
words <- c("word1", "word2", "word3")
text <- "This is a text made off of word1 and possibly word2 and so on."
```

The output should return TRUE if any of the words is founded in text and which word is founded.

Comment: You are right. That's what happens when you go back and forth between R and Python...:)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`grepl` to the rescue.

```
sapply(words, grepl, text)

# word1 word2 word3 
#  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

This considers each element of `words`, in turn, and returns a logical (`TRUE` if the the word appears in `text`, and `FALSE` if not).

If you want to ensure that the *exact* words are sought, then you can use:

```
sapply(words, function(x) grepl(sprintf('\\b%s\\b', x), text))
```

This will prevent `word1` from returning `TRUE` when text has `sword123` but lacks `word1`. It might make less sense though if `words` has multi-word elements.

Comment: What is `'\\b%s\\b'` exactly doing?

Comment: `\\b` indicates a word boundary, so by surrounding a string with a pair of `\\b`, we tell `grep` that we only want whole words to be matched. The `%s` is a placeholder used by `sprintf`, and is replaced by `x` when `sprintf` is evaluated. Here it's equivalent to `paste0('\\b', x, '\\b')`, but I prefer it for it's simplicity and versatility. See `?sprintf` for more.

Comment: Well explained. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Look at the package `stringr`.
I think the function you need to use is `str_detect` or `str_locate_all`. It's is to include this function in `sapply`.

> library(stringr)
>
> str_detect(text, words)
>
> str_locate_all(text, words)

Answer (score 1):

[rflashtext](https://github.com/AbrJA/rflashtext) can help if `length(words)` is huge and you need to extract only exact words `'\\b%s\\b'`.

```
library(rflashtext)

processor <- keyword_processor$new()
processor$add_keys_words(keys = words)
words_found <- processor$find_keys(sentence = text)
length(words_found) > 0 # TRUE if any of the words is found
do.call(rbind, words_found) # Found words with spam info (end of word + 1)
     word    start end
[1,] "word1" 28    33 
[2,] "word2" 47    52
```

A little benchmark:

```
words <- sprintf("word%s", seq_len(n))
text <- "This is a text made off of word1 and possibly word2 and so on."

processor <- keyword_processor$new()
processor$add_keys_words(keys = words)

microbenchmark(sapply = sapply(words, grepl, text),
               sapply_exact = sapply(words, function(x) grepl(sprintf('\\b%s\\b', x), text)),
               stringr = str_locate_all(text, words),
               stringr_exact = str_locate_all(text, sprintf('\\b%s\\b', words)),
               rflashtext = processor$find_keys(sentence = text), unit = "relative")

# n = 10

Unit: relative
          expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq        max neval
        sapply 1.009416 1.031136 1.024220 1.029903 1.026094  1.2367347   100
  sapply_exact 1.468927 1.468864 1.670976 1.468777 1.471380 13.8183673   100
       stringr 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000  1.0000000   100
 stringr_exact 1.137476 1.143773 1.122424 1.131047 1.135522  0.8173469   100
    rflashtext 1.841808 1.903846 1.885012 1.878628 1.853535  3.1908163   100

# n = 1000

Unit: relative
          expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
        sapply 44.29630 36.76002 32.37855 32.26093 29.48758 15.99403   100
  sapply_exact 67.19219 55.81263 50.64435 48.81392 45.08299 57.05292   100
       stringr 42.92593 35.09389 30.65920 30.61525 27.93996 13.76364   100
 stringr_exact 48.59459 39.88304 35.12447 34.80867 32.10688 16.74084   100
    rflashtext  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000   100
```